# Count amount of buildings (floating polygons) within neighbourhoods

Tags: qgis, dissolve

I want to count the amount of buildings within my neighbourhoods. The dissolve function doesn't work here because the buildings are not intersecting. Does someone have a tip on how I can do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Make sure your buildings have an ID.

Step 2: `Join attributes by location` in order to get the name/ID of your neighbourhoods to your buildings.

Step 3: Run `count("building ID",group_by:="neighbourhood ID")` in the field calculator on the joined layer. Column names have to be replaced by the one your data has.

Comment: How can I quickly give the buildings an ID? The building layer does not have information yet in which neighbourhood it is in.

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=id#expression-function-record-and-attributes-id

Comment: Your building layer looks like it comes from a cadastral dataset or from OpenStreetMap so I would imagine that each feature already has a unique identifier. Check the attribute table.